# Stored procedure overdoes - inserting multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I expect below procedure to insert one row into the orders table, grab the PK then insert it into the orderlines table this PK with as many lines as many are in the datagridview on the form, then update the stock table with the quantity and finally insert 1 row into the payments table. Unfortunately it inserts as many rows to all 3 tables as many rows are in the datagridview. Is there a way to achieve my goal preferably without braking it down into more procedures?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNewSale
    @customer INT, -- passed from a comboBox
    @staff VARCHAR(12), -- the user logged in
    @product INT, -- passed from a comboBox
    @quantity INT -- passed from a textBox
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO orders (order_cust_id, order_staff_id, order_date) -- order_id (PK) = identity autoincremented
    VALUES (@customer, 
            (SELECT logons.logon_st_id FROM logons 
             WHERE logons.logon_name = @staff), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

    DECLARE @ordernbr INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO orderlines (ol_order_id, ol_pro_id, ol_qty, ol_value) -- ol_id (PK) = identity autoincremented
    VALUES (@ordernbr, @product, @quantity, 
            @quantity * (SELECT products.pro_price 
                         FROM products WHERE pro_id = @product));

    UPDATE products 
    SET pro_stock = (pro_stock - @quantity)  
    WHERE pro_id = @product;

    INSERT INTO payments (paym_order_id, paym_amount, paym_taken_by, paym_date) -- paym_id (PK) = identity autoincremented
    VALUES (@ordernbr, 
            (SELECT SUM(orderlines.ol_value) AS paym_amount 
             FROM orderlines WHERE orderlines.ol_order_id = @ordernbr),
            (SELECT logons.logon_st_id FROM logons 
             WHERE logons.logon_name = @staff), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
END
```

Comment: As written this procedure can never insert anything but one row into every table (since the `VALUES` clauses specify only one row each), so if you're getting more rows than you want it's because it's called multiple times -- in code not shown here.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, your procedure takes individual parameters and (aside from there being a simpler way to do your inserts) can only insert a single row with the `values` criteria, so you must be calling the procedure multiple times.

Comment: _as many rows are in the datagridview_ The most likely cause is your application code calling this procedure for each row. Your application logic (and perhaps the associated GUI) is not designed correctly. You need to insert one order first and then insert multiple orderlines for that newly inserted order.

Comment: Had a feeling about the procedure completes each time / row since is in a loop. @SMor, if I insert the orders table first how do I pass the ordernumber (PK) to the orderlines (FK) table?

Comment: Ideally I think you should call the procedure once and pass it a list of products, so build a list of ID values and pass it either as a json array or using a table-type parameter.

Comment: Aside: If you want the date/time assigned to the rows in various tables to be the same then you should capture a value at the beginning of the procedure, e.g. `declare @Now as DateTime = Current_Timestamp;`, and use that value where needed.

Comment: @dtb This is done in your application code - which you have not posted. I'm certain you can find many many examples of order processing in any programming language.

Comment: _as many rows are in the datagridview_ For this you need to use same select query from which you are binding your gridview.